# Работа оператора сравнения

Tags: php

Вот код на PHP. Прогоняю переменную через INTVAL, получаю две разные. Почему IF видит их как равные?

```
$a='123xxx';
$b=intval($a);

echo '<br/>',$a;
echo '<br/>',$b;

if ($a==$b) echo '<br/>true';
```

Comment: Потому что это PHP, и сравнение в нем работает так:  
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php  
Интерпретатор пытается привести типы- в Вашем случае число к строке и у него это успешно получается, впрочем  

    $b==$a
он тоже успешно сможет привести к одному типу.

Comment: $b=(int)$a;

Comment: и используйте ===